# How to use parse incoming json objects which have field “description” to a Core Data entity?

Tags: ios

I have a problem with my core data model. In my entity I have an attribute `description`. But when I want to set this attribute, I get the following error:

> Property name clashes with a method implemented by NSManagedObject or
>   NSObject

How do I overwrite it? I want to use description as an attribute name because I'm getting it from a web service.

How do I write a custom JSON parser which will do the work of converting the  `description` attribute to something else in my CoreData model?

Comment: Listen to the excellent advice given by Wain. Like the old joke "Doctor, doctor, it hurts when I poke a spoon in my eye". "Don't do it then". "Doctor, it still hurts when I poke a spoon in my eye".

Answer (score 2):

Don't, use a different name, like `overview` or something. `description` is a common built in method and you shouldn't try to use it for something else (though you can override it to provide a suitable description, you should call `super` to get a complete description).

Comment: How can i use description as attribute name.or any other way to do it.

Comment: here i'm getting json response with description file and now i'm saving that json to core data

Comment: Save it with a different name, consider `description` as reserved

Comment: any other way with out changing the name

Comment: change it, you will run into weird situations if you try to reuse it, it can be really confusing, and it really isn't that hard to change it